# Pulling data from several worksheets and dropping into table on a summary worksheet (looping error)

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, excel-2010

I have created the code below to grab specific data from multiple sheets within the workbook, and placing them in rows on a summary sheet.  It either populates nothing or populates every row over and over again.  It needs to occur automatically.

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim WkSht as Worksheet
    Dim Row as Integer

    'A15 - A29: Pull over (A1) if > 0
    'B15 - B29: Pull over (C1) if > 0
    'C15 - C29: Pull over (D7) if > 0

    For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Row = 15 To 29
            If WkSht.Name Like "Tr. [0-9]*" Then
                If WkSht.Range("D7").Value > 0 Then
                    If IsEmpty(Row) Then
                        Cells(Row, 1).Value = WkSht.Range("A1").Value
                        Cells(Row, 2).Value = WkSht.Range("C1").Value
                        Cells(Row, 3).Value = WkSht.Range("D7").Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next Row
    Next WkSht
End Sub
```

Comment: Not really sure I read a question here, but would suggest: walk this code with F8, and pause after the first "Cells(Row,1)..." Ctrl-G to the immediate window and manually check the input and output params... both the range addresses and their values.

Comment: Needs a bit more explanation of what the intent of the code is - exactly what needs to be copied from where to where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the following changes will help (a bit hard without seeing your entire workbook):

1. Define the summary sheet as a separate entity - don't scrape data from it
2. Instead of testing for `isempty(Row)`, test for the *thing* you want to be empty (a cell? `Row` is a variable that you set a few lines earlier)
3. Reference `Cells` on the summary sheet, not "by themselves". You can't be sure what Excel will be thinking (what sheet is active) when you do this.
4. You are copying the same thing over and over again because of the `For Row =` loop inside the `For Each` loop. You just want to increment `Row` once for each worksheet found.

What you end up with is this - does that work?

```
Sub Summary()

    Dim WkSht as Worksheet
    Dim summarySheet as Worksheet
    Dim Row as Integer

    'A15 - A29: Pull over (A1) if > 0
    'B15 - B29: Pull over (C1) if > 0
    'C15 - C29: Pull over (D7) if > 0

    Set summarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary") ' whatever the right name is…

    Row = 15
    For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        if Not (WkSht.Name = summarySheet.Name) Then
            If WkSht.Name Like "Tr. [0-9]*" Then
                If WkSht.Range("D7").Value > 0 Then
                    If IsEmpty(summarySheet.Cells(Row,1)) Then
                        summarySheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value = WkSht.Range("A1").Value
                        summarySheet.Cells(Row, 2).Value = WkSht.Range("C1").Value
                        summarySheet.Cells(Row, 3).Value = WkSht.Range("D7").Value
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Row = Row + 1
        End If
    Next WkSht
End Sub
```

Your comment in the code suggests you want to move things if they are greater than zero only but your code only tests one value; did you intend to test all three?

Comment: Title (A1), Description (C1), and Total (D7) need to be copied from any worksheet named "Tr. #" to rows in a table on the "Summary" sheet (A15:C29), if the Total is greater than 0 (i.e. the sheet is considered active).

Comment: Thanks, Floris.  It appears that solved my problem!  Wish I would have asked days ago.  =D

Comment: Glad I could help - apparently my guesses were sufficient… and if you hadn't spent time trying to solve this you would not appreciate me as much (!!) ;-)

Comment: By the way - as you could tell from some of the comments: formulating your problem _very precisely_ is a huge help in getting a solution. Often, just _trying_ to explain what your program is trying to do is sufficient to get it working yourself. Your question was pretty fuzzy - reflecting that you had not quite figured out how things worked. It's a good skill to work on. This comes with practice, practice, practice… Keep asking, keep learning!

Comment: +1 i'm sure it takes a lot of effort second guessing what OP intends to do :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - coming from you that means a lot.